# .htaccess redirect error with query string change

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a URL that is:

`http://example.com?country=uk&animal=dog&size=large`

I wish to change the query string to

`http://example.com?country=uk&animal=cat&size=small`

I have tried this in an .htaccess tester

```sh
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*[&?]|)animal=(dog)&size=(large)([&?].*|)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?%1animal=cat&size=small[R=301,NC,L]
```

But the & in the rewrite keeps getting shown a `686` !

`http://example.com?country=uk&animal=cat686size=small`

any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have more rules in this .htaccess? Can these parameters be in any order in query string?

Comment: No I have to keep them in that order as it is a stacked process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following htaccess Rules. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
##making engine one here.
RewriteEngine ON
##External redirect rule goes here. Please make sure to use correct back references to be used later on.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/([^?]*)\?(country=)uk&(animal=)dog(&size=)large [NC]
##Applying redirection with 301 redirect here.
RewriteRule ^ /%1?%2uk&%3cat&%4small [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks @RavinderSingh13 i'm using https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ to test the action, but it is saying that the `%{THE_REQUEST} is an unsuported string?

Comment: @Jay-UK, Please don't online sites to test your Rules, they don't work correctly, test it in your apache server and let me know then, cheers.

Comment: thanks for the advice there, so close now ! That makes the changes but insted of using the URL it inserts the entire file directory to the page, ie https://example.com/var/www/vhosts/example.com/?country=uk&animal=cat&size=small

Comment: @Jay-UK, sure, it's fixed now please do check it once and let me know if this helps you. Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

Comment: Hey Ravindaer that’s brilliant. Works a treat. Many thanks for your help.